# Android get person_id from MMS

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, mms

I'm in a very big trouble in building a simple custom SMS/MMS content provider wrapper class as long as it doesn't exist an official one for the android platform.
Obviously, to get data, i query on the "content://sms" and "content://mms" content provider using a cursor.

I found it fairly simple with SMS, because the columns names are quite intelligible and contains all data that a typical programmer needs in his application ("person" to get the sms sender/receiver contact id, "address" to get the sender/receiver phone number, "type" to get if the sms is an inbox, outbox, draft, sended sms etc...)

Unfortunately with MMS i've found a lot of trouble. The columns has unintelligible names (ex. "d_tm", "ct_cls", "retr_st", "d_rpt" etc.) and basic informations that i need, such as contact id, phone number, the type of the mms etc... seems to miss.

How can i get this information over the MMS?
I searched over all the 32 columns of the content provider but i didn't found what i need.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.
I know that google advise to avoid this kind of "low-level" operation over content providers that doesn't have a series of official class to access them, but i imagine that software house that operates in sms/mms management such as HandCent or Go Dev team, have built their own content provider using the same approach i'm using too.
Am i right or it exists unofficial libraries to manage SMS/MMS?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why the "-1" on my question...maybe i didn't posted the question in a clear way...

Comment: "content://mms/part" this you need to pass in Uri

Comment: Tried your solution...and as expected, it doesn't work :(. As far as i know with "content://mms/part" uri, you can get all information about the single part of MMSs (audio, video, image attachements etc). There are no information about contact_id or the type of the MMS...other suggestions?

Comment: first of all your question doesn't have any code so how people can understand what you have tried before asking here hence they give -ve voting.

Comment: Usually i post the code, but in this case i couldn't because all procedures that i'm developing involves huge number of business logic's code lines, custom classes and interfaces that may confuse people of community...so i tried to explain my problem the best i can, but i'm italian and my english isn't very good :) BTW thanks 4 all!

Comment: @GiveEmTheBoot.. that's why i up-vote your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled a little bit more and finally i found that the correct way to get information like contact_id, phone number, type etc. about MMSs, is to open the content provider to the following

```
 URI: "content://mms/{MmsId}/addr"
```

> ({MmsId} is the MMS "_id" column value).

Here i found all information i need.

Hope it helps!!!